# Zend Framework 2: Module directory naming convention?

Tags: php, directory, zend-framework2

I am just getting my feet wet with Zend Framework 2, following some tutorials.
Having created several modules today, I always struggle with how to name the different folders.

So far I understood that `module/src/Mymodule` is named after the namespace (Mymodule in this case) defined in Module.php. That way its possible for the autoloader to find the right folder I suppose.

But what about the directory structure in `module/view`? Following the Mymodule example, the correct path for the views would be `module/view/mymodule/{action name}/{action name}.phtml`. Why is mymodule written in lowercase this time?

Also I've seen examples where the structure was something like `module/view/mymodule/mymodule/{action name}.phtml`. What is going on there?

I know that this is probably depends on configuration & code structure, but at least the usage of uppercase & lowercase names must have some general sense I hope ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way. Folders are always lowercase, with two exceptions:

- Folders containing PHP classes always use StudlyCaps, as per [PSR-1](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md)
- The module folders (things in `module/`) are generally named the same as the module namespace, e.g. `Mymodule` from your example

Comment: +1 There is also the documentation for [coding standards](https://zf2-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/coding.standard.html#naming-conventions) and the recommended [module structure](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/project.structure.html?highlight=Caching#recommended-project-structure-for-zend-framework-mvc-applications)

Comment: That project/module structure doc is wildly inaccurate is it relates to ZF1. I'm not sure what that's doing in the ZF2 docs - will check.

Comment: Woops, I didn't actually look at the content of the link! I had assumed it was the ZF2 page as like you say shouldn't be in there.